# how to automatically log request and response xml in rest web service using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jaxb

I am developing rest web services in java. I need to automatically **log** request and response xml in **rest web service using JAXB**.

Following is my rest service.

```
    @POST 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/xmlCall")
    @Override
    public XmlCallOutput postXmlCall(Xmlcall xmlCall){

            return xmlCallInService.acceptXmlCallData(xmlCall);

    }
```

Here i want to log **Xmlcall** and **XmlCallOutput** object in form of xml. Is there any straight forward way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can log the request/response before and after convertion to/from objects. This is not as trivial as you might expect, the key is to implement some interface like so:

```
public class PrettyPrinterLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter, WriterInterceptor {
..
}
```

and plug into the existing infrastructure. I've written a [small library](https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/tree/master/jax-rs#class-annotation) that does this, for a working example.